# Using Global Workflow + Saving a Site as Templete will create many orphans workflow status fields

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, administration, configuration, orphan

I just noticed a problem inside our live sharepoint 2013 sites. now i have a team site collection. and inside this site collection i define the following:-

1. I create a sub-site based on the "Team" site template.
2. inside this sub-site i add some custom lists.
3. these custom lists are using custom content types.
4. the custom content types are linked with global workflows.
5. now these global workflows will automatically create new "workflow status" fields on the lists when they execute.
6. then i save this sub-site as template. and i created new sub-sites based on this site template.
7. now as i was modifying the global workflows and saving some sub-sites as templates.. today i realize that some lists inside the sub-sites have many list columns representing orphans workflow status columns (some of these WF status columns were inside the original template sub-site!!).

for example. when i first create the first Template sub-site, i tested the lists and their global workflows.. where new "workflow status" list columns were created. now when i saved this sub-site as template and i create new sub-sites based on the template, i have noticed that SharePoint will create new "workflow status" columns instead of using the original ones which are inside the site template!!... so this result in orphans workflow status fields.. so can anyone adivce how i can remove these orphans workflow status columns? as on some scenario if i save a sub-site which contain orphans "workflow status" columns as template, and i try to create new sub-site based on this site template, i will get error such as "“Feature schema contain wrong field name” .. so can anyone adivce on this please?i need to get rid of these columns as they are breaking my sites??

Thanks